# Getting an error while trying to create a site collection in SharePoint Central Administration

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I recently installed SharePoint 2016 server on my machine with Windows Server 2012 R2 OS. The setup completed successfully. I have also installed all the prerequisites manually. After that I created a database by using powershell command as: "New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName SharePoint_Config -DatabaseServer WINDOWS2012\SQLEXPRESS AdministrationContentDatabaseName SharePoint_Admin_Content_DB -LocalServerRole SingleServerFarm"

It created database successfully. But, after finishing a configuration wizard, the welcome page shown error as: "
Sorry, something went wrong
The page cannot be displayed because your server's current configuration does not support it. To perform this task, use the command line operations in Stsadm.exe.
TECHNICAL DETAILS

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 0968929e-f0a3-3089-0000-0b53be4469bf

Date and Time: 9/26/2018 10:52:05 AM
"

Then, I opened central administration and tried to create a site collection, but it showed the same error as above. The same error is occurring while running the configuration wizard from the central administration.
I am unable to find the exact solution for this issue. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks and regards,
Purushottam Patil
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO7WC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was using a wrong powershell command to create a database. After that, I corrected the mistake and created a database again.

The powershell command that I used to solve the issue is:
New-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseName "Your_Database_Name" -DatabaseServer "Database_Server_Name" -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString "Your_Passphrase" -AsPlainText -force) -FarmCredentials (Get-Credential) -LocalServerRole SingleServerFarm

By using the above command, I created a database and run the configuration wizard. The wizard completed successfully and then a welcome page appeared.